# University Assignment And I'm out of logics

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have tried everything but the code doesn't work and i'm out of logics as i'm new in this field

[Here's the assignment description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHfjb.jpg)

here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   char* Array2D[3][2] = {{"Bushra","0000-555555"},{"Ahad","0000-555544"},{"Mehwish","042-5558585"}};

   char* name;
   std::cout << "Enter name to find number in the directory"; 
   std::cout << "\n" << "\n";
   std::cin >> name;

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<< "Array[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << Array2D[i][j] << "\n";
            std::cout<< "\n";

         if(name == Array2D[i])
{
        std::cout << Array2D[j];
}
else
{
std::cout << "NO RECORD";
}

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post code as code please.

Comment: What do you mean by that sir ?

Comment: It means you did not pay attention while taking Stack Overflow's introductory tour today.

Comment: Excerpt from the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help): *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: Good example of how to do a very bad post!

Comment: I'm really sorry about that because i want to submit this project tomorrow :(

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: I have pasted the whole code here and please guide me the through the description in the picture. @abelenky

Comment: Really, submit by tomorrow?  You haven't typed anything that we could see.  Maybe you could post your instructor's email so we can send the homework directly and save you the trouble.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work".  What inputs were used?  How does the expected output differ from the actual input?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews check the code and the image too.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow the link, firewalls are blocking my access.  How about if you paste text instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `operator==` with C-Style strings.
You will have to use `strcmp()`.

If you used `std::string` instead, you could use `operator==`.

**Edit 1**:
The problem is that the `==` operator is comparing *pointers* and not what the *pointers are pointing to*.

Answer (score 0):

[**Source in IDEOne**](http://ideone.com/OUWFZf)

***Now modified to use a 2-D Array.***
This is how I would do it in C++ using a modern compiler.
Your assignment may be different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(void) {

  string phoneBook[3][2] = { { "Jenni", "867-5309"  },
                             { "Police", "911-911"  },
                             { "Operator", "123456" } };

   string searchName;

   cout << "Enter Name to find a number" << std::endl;
   cin >> searchName;

   auto t = std::find_if(phoneBook, phoneBook+3, [&](auto& r){return r[0] == searchName;} );
   cout << ((t == phoneBook+3)? "No Such Name Found" : (*t)[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to do it by two dimensional array sir.

Comment: 'T'does not name a type and the other error is 'T' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: I demonstrated that it works on the IDEOne website.  If it does not work for you, you are using an older compiler.